# Convergence of $\prod_{k=1}^n \left( I_d + \frac{1}{n} A\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \right)$ for $A : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbf{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-exponential

**The problem**

Let $d \geq 1$ and $A : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbf{R})$ be a continuous function. For $n \geq 1$, define:

$$
E_n := \prod_{k=1}^n \left( I_d + \frac{1}{n} A \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)  \right)
$$

The goal is to study the convergence of $(E_n)_{n \geq 1}$. I would like to find when (under which conditions on $A$) this sequence converges, to which limit, and when it does not converge.

**My try**

My first idea is to show that:

$$
E_n \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} \exp \left( \int_0^1 A  \right)
$$

I have succeeded to prove it for $d = 1$. It consists in taking the logarithm of $E_n$, use the inequalities $x - \frac{x^2}{2} \leq \ln(1+x) \leq x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ and finally the squeeze theorem and Riemann sums.

The result is also true when $A$ is a constant matrix.

But I have a hard time to generalize the proof with logarithms. I know one can define the logarithm of matrices not too far from $I_d$, but nothing about the additivity of this logarithm.

Comment: Concerning the Jordan form of $A(t)=P(t)\cdot\Sigma(t)\cdot P^{-1}(t)$, does any one knows if the continuity of $A$ imply the continuity of $P$ and $\Sigma$ and $P^{-1}$ ? Also if it implies that $P$ is constant then the proof is easy but I doubt it. I feel like the continuity of $\Sigma$ would imply that the Jordan blocks need to stay the same hence the multiplicity of the eigenvalues are the same and they are continuous function themselves.

Comment: The product notation seems ambiguous to me, as the matrix product is not commutative in general and the product notation does not specify the order of multiplication. Now, if one defines $B : [0, 1] \to \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbb{R})$ by $$ B(t) := \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(I_d+\frac{A(1/n)}{n}\right)\cdots\left(I_d+\frac{A(\lfloor nt\rfloor/n)}{n}\right), $$ then $B$ solves the equation $$ B'(t) = B(t)A(t) $$ and thus $B$ can be realized via *ordered exponential*.

Comment: Here, the product means $(I_d + \frac{1}{n} A(\frac{1}{n})) \cdots (I_d + \frac{1}{n} A(\frac{n}{n}))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the convergence, we write

$$ X_{n,i} := \frac{1}{n^i} \sum_{1 \leq k_1 < \cdots < k_i \leq n} A\bigl(\tfrac{k_1}{n}\bigr)\cdots A\bigl(\tfrac{k_i}{n}\bigr). $$

(Here, we set $X_{n,0} := I_d$ and $X_{n,i} := 0$ for $i > n$.) Then we may write the product as

$$ E_n := \biggl(I_d + \frac{A\bigl(\tfrac{1}{n}\bigr)}{n} \biggr) \cdots \biggl(I_d + \frac{A\bigl(\tfrac{n}{n}\bigr)}{n}\biggr)
= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{n,i}. $$

Since the operator norm of $X_{n,i}$ admits the uniform bound

$$ \| X_{n,i} \| \leq \frac{1}{i!} \|A\|_{\sup}^i $$

with $\|A\|_{\sup} := \sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} \|A(t)\|$, Weierstrass M-test shows that $E_n$ converges provided $X_{n,i}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ for each $i$. But if we write $\mathcal{T}_i := \{ (t_1, \cdots, t_i) : 0 \leq t_1 \leq \cdots \leq t_i \leq 1\}$, then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n,i} = \int_{\mathcal{T}_i} A(t_1) \cdots A(t_i) \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \cdots \mathrm{d} t_i, $$

the desired conclusion follows. Moreover, we obtain:

> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(I_d + \frac{A\bigl(\tfrac{1}{n}\bigr)}{n} \biggr) \cdots \biggl(I_d + \frac{A\bigl(\tfrac{n}{n}\bigr)}{n}\biggr) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathcal{T}_i} A(t_1) \cdots A(t_i) \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \cdots \mathrm{d} t_i. $$

If $\{ A(t) \}_{t \in [0, 1]}$ commutes, then the above integral reduces to

$$ \int_{\mathcal{T}_i} A(t_1) \cdots A(t_i) \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \cdots \mathrm{d} t_i
= \frac{1}{n!} \biggl( \int_{0}^{1} A(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr)^i $$

and thus the limit of $E_n$ becomes the matrix exponential $\exp\bigl( \int_{0}^{1} A(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \bigr)$. But we do not expect this to happen in general.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong. Reason for $d=2$ and consider the matrices $$ T := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad S : =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ Notice that we do not have $\exp(T + S) = \exp(T)\exp(S)$ by a simple computation, which can be done noticing that $$ S^2 = -I_2  \text{  and  } T^n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n\\0 &1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ for all integers $n$. Now if we relax the condition on $A$ to be only piecewise continuous, it is then clear that the statement fails: take $A(t) = 2T$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $A(t) = 2S$ on $(1/2,1]$ and use the fact that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(I_2 + \frac{M}{n} \right)^n = \exp(M) $$ for all matrices $M$. Now the idea is just to approximate this piecewise constant function by an affine function. Reason by contradiction and suppose $E_n$ converges for all continuous functions to $\exp(\int_0^1 A)$. Let $N$ be an integer indexing the sequence of continuous function $(A_N)$ where $A_N$ is defined to be constant equal to $2T$ on $[0,1/2]$, an affine function connecting $2T$ to $2S$ on $[1/2, 1/2 + 1/N]$ and equal to $S$ on $[1/2 + 1/N, 1]$. Then the product $E^N_{2n}$ associated with this function $A_N$ can be written as $$E^N_{2n} = \left( I_2 + \frac{T}{n} \right)^n \cdot \; \prod_{k=n}^{n+ \lfloor 2n/N \rfloor } (I_2 + (1/2n)A_N(k/n)) \cdot (I_2 + S/n)^{n - \lfloor 2n/N \rfloor}$$ Both left and right side of this product converge to $\exp(T)$ and $\exp(S(1-2/N))$ respectively by easy estimations. Therefore since $E_n^N$ converges, it must be that the term in the middle converges as well, say towards a matrix $M_N$. We hence have the relation $$\exp\left(\int_0^1 A_N\right) = \exp(T)M_N\exp(S(1-2/N)) $$ The norm (say the infinity norm on the coefficients) of $M_N - I_2$ is the limit of the norm of the product in the middle minus the identity, this norm is bounded by $(1 + 1/2n)^{\lfloor2n/N\rfloor} -1$ (expand the product without using commutativity and use the triangle inequality), hence $\|M_N - I_2 \| \leq e^{1/N} -1 $, thus $M_N$ converges towards $I_2$ as $N$ approaches infinity. Now you just have to let $N \to \infty$ in the formula above to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Could you detail the end? How does approximating help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have reformulated the problem. Indeed, I am not absolutely certain the limit exists and is the exponential of the integral of $A$.

Comment: Is it clearer ?